# Good, secure encryption

Tags: c#, .net, security, file-transfer

Hi im thinking about developing a sort of File Transfer program and was wondering if i want as good encryption that i can get what should i use?

ill be developing this with c# so i got access to the .net lib :P
having a certificate with me on my usb to access the server is no problem if that would increase the security!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest built in way with the .NET Framework is probably to use the [SslStream](https://web.archive.org/web/20170906055838/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx)  class which is built in. Example of usage [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200220153113/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/luskan/archive/2007/10/01/115758.aspx).

Comment: is there any way to encrypt a byte array without having to use a sslstream?

Comment: Sure. Many to choose from, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Look into tunneling your connection through [SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security).  It does all the hard work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap a stream around a regular array using System.IO.MemoryStream.